# How to make Django Model run some function when create

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

### what I want

I have a column `video_length` in a model called `Episode`, and another column `sum_length` in another model `Series`.

I want `sum_length` only update when episode create, don't update when i modify it.

### How i do this now?

now, i override the save function,and add a function call to update it, just like this.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.excerpt:
        md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=[
            'markdown.extensions.extra',
            'markdown.extensions.codehilite',
        ])
        self.excerpt = strip_tags(md.convert(self.description))[:54]
        self.series.addlength(self.video_length)
    super(Episode, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As  `excerpt` is generated by markdown content I think that when `excerpt` is blank is saved, not updated.

### Why i ask this question ?

1. my workaround is useable ,but I want to find a more pythonic code
2. my workaround will not update when I really need  update it.

### What you can give me ?

maybe a sample code is fine

### other information

Django :1.11.6
Python :3.6.3
Database: MySQL

**Thanks For your answer**

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways this can be done.

1. Override the save() method just like you did already

   The are also two ways to check if the object was saved already or not.

   a. check primary key(pk).

   We can simply check if the primary is None since the primary key set only after the object saved in the database.

   ```
   self.pk is None  
       #not saved
   else
       #already saved instance
   ```

   this solution won't work properly if you have set **(primary_key=True)** in you model class.

   b. Django also provides another way to check this

   from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading

   ```
   if self._state.adding == True 
      #not saved
   elif self._state.adding == False 
      #already saved instance
   ```
2. Implement post_save signal
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

   The singal provides an boolean attribute with name **created**. Its value will be **true if a new record was created or False it the record was created already**.
   This is the most cleaner solution and must be used if you want to implement too many logics

   Follow this simple tutorial to implement post save signal https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Choose the first option if the logics are simple and you want the feature only for one model.

Choose the second option depending upon the lenth of your code and if you want to extent the feature for more than one model class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the save of the model you can move this functionality into the model form. It will give you more flexibility.

In this case you can create two different forms, let's say one for normal users, for which excerpt will be updated on creation and admin form which will rewrite excerpt if it is necessary.

```
class AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Episode

  def save(self, excerpt=None, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):

    object = super(Episode, self).save(commit=commit)

    if excerpt:
        object.excerpt = excerpt

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Episode

  def save(self, excerpt=None, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):

    object = super(Episode, self).save(commit=commit)

    if not object.excerpt and excerpt:
        object.excerpt = excerpt
```